# How to handle the response from PayPal In-Context in AngularJS instead of NodeJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, paypal, onsen-ui, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm having trouble getting a response from server side NodeJS code after checking out using PayPal In-Context via the paypal-rest-sdk.

I have a PayPal form defined in html, and purposefully did not define the action. I only defined the id and method (get). In my Angular code, I define the action when the PayPal button is clicked:

```
var payPalForm = document.getElementById('payPalForm');

payPalForm.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

  payPalForm.setAttribute('action', "https://10.0.0.25:8001/checkout/" +
    $scope.user._id + "/" + $scope.viewEvent._id.valueOf() + "/" + 
    $scope.viewEvent.eventName + "/" + $scope.viewEvent.price);

});
```

By doing this, I am able to successfully checkout via PayPal In-Context.

In my NodeJS code, after successful checkout, instead of `return res.end();` if successful or `res.sendStatus(400, 'bad paypal payment');` if failure, I would like to pass the status back to the Angular, and handle it there.

To reiterate: I do not want to define the post PayPal In-Context route in NodeJS, I would like to do it in Angular.

I need to do this being I am using [Onsen UI](https://onsen.io/), and am using a [splitter](http://tutorial.onsen.io/?framework=angular1&category=Reference&module=splitter) to navigate between pages.

Has anyone successfully done this?

***UPDATE AFTER ATTEMPTING THE FIRST ANSWER***

I have tried this before, but after attempting to implement Ilia Sky's Answer, the result is the PayPal In-Context checkout does not execute correctly. The script runs correctly (as determined by output in the terminal), but the In-Context window loads with "?" as a parameter and then immediately closes itself. Here are screenshots on how I updated my code. The commented out code is what I had when I was able to successfully checkout, but unable to redirect properly:
[image: Controller]
[image: Service]

I think this is an issue with PayPal, and I'm not sure how to solve it.

This is why I'm wondering if I can listen for a redirect in Angular, and then load a different page when a certain redirect is identified.

I tried this in my Angular controllers, but it only ever executed when the initial page loaded:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encourage everyone to check out this [link](https://github.com/paypaldev/node-app-examples/tree/master/kraken-angular-in-context).

One of the PayPal developers has posted a sample Kraken with Angular example of the PayPal In-Context Checkout.

Answer (score 2):

I may be wrong, but from what I understand what you want to do is:

1. Send data to the server (to `https://10.0.0.25:8001/checkout/...`)
2. Do something on the server and give a response (`res.send` etc)
3. Handle the response on the client

Right?

To do this the easiest solution would be just to send an ajax request to the server and then handle the response.

This means instead of changing the action attribute you can directly make the request via js. With angular that would be done using the [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service.

```
$http.post('https://10.0...').then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

And in `success|errorCallback` you can do whatever you want such as load a page in the splitter or whatever you want :)

To change what happens when you try to submit the form you can check out [`ng-submit`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit).

And to get `$http` you can just add it to your list of arguments for your controller.

Example

```
app.controller('ExampleController', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.submit = function() {
    $http.post('your/long/url').then(function(response) {
      mySplitter.content.load('success-page.html');
    }, function(response) {
      mySplitter.content.load('error-page.html');  
    });
  };
}]);

<form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  ...
</form>
```

Comment: Well... here's the thing. I need to initialize all my PayPal forms (buttons) upon loading the initial page, in Javascript. It is where I inject the PayPal script into them as well. In the initial controller, I set a scope variable equal to one of the PayPal forms. Then when I navigate to another page (which uses a different controller) that will contain one of the PayPal forms (buttons) I created, I set a scope variable in this controller equal to the scope variable in the other controller. Then I append this as a child of a div in the new page I am on. Therefore, I can not use ng-submit.

Comment: I'm wondering if I can listen for a specific redirect in Angular, and then use my splitter to load a different page based on what the redirect is. The redirect would be different depending on if the PayPal process was a success or a fail.

Comment: If I don't initialize all the PayPal forms (buttons) at once, and inject the script into all of them at the same time, then I receive an error for trying to inject the script more than once.

Comment: Hi - sorry I didn't completely understand you after the first 3 comments. Looking at your update it seems that the form may still be sending itself since you say that you can see a `?` in your url. To fix it you can change the `click` to `submit` and then add `e.preventDefault()`.